Перевод Dicom в multiframe DICOM
Есть библиотека которая поддерживает только multiframe DICOM , несколько dicom не получается в нее запихнуть. Подскажите как отдельные dicom соединить в multiframe DICOM?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вы ищете стороннее приложение или библиотеку на каком-то определенном языке программирования? Упомянутая библиотека не может быть заменена на другую?
